# sql query error

Tags: sql

```
select E.Job_ID, count(*), max(Employee_Salary) as kos, avg(Employee_Salary)
    from Employee E  
    inner join JOB D on E.Job_ID = D.Job_ID
    group by E.Job_ID
```

I want to order my result by D.Functio but i have this error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'JOB.Functio' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Is that the complete query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `D.Functio` in the `Select` and `Group by`

```
select E.Job_ID, D.Functio,
     count(*), max(Employee_Salary) as kos, avg(Employee_Salary)
from Employee E  
inner join JOB D on E.Job_ID = D.Job_ID
group by E.Job_ID, D.Functio
order by D.Functio
```

Answer (score 2):

What is unclear about the error message?  You are trying to order by something that is not being aggregated.  Here is one solution:

```
order by max(d.Functio)
```

The problem is that the alias "job" is not known.  You need to use the "d" that you assigned to the table.

This should work, since there is presumably one job.Functio per job id.  Another fix is to change the `group by` to:

```
group by e.Job_ID, d.Job.Functio
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add it to your GROUP BY if it's a descriptive column (job function?)

```
select E.Job_ID, count(*), max(Employee_Salary) as kos, avg(Employee_Salary)
    from Employee E  
    inner join JOB D on E.Job_ID = D.Job_ID
    group by E.Job_ID, D.Functio
    order by D.Functio
```

Otherwise in the ordering you need to apply an aggregate function like min(), max(), avg() etc.